# adding dynamic option value to live search select plugin

Tags: php, performance

i am using a bootstrap's live search select plugin which is created by [silviomoreto](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) i am having one complication!

what was previosuly happening that there was a standard select box in which i use to add dynamic option values, now the list has become so long that i do have to implement search feature in the selectbox! this is how i was previously doing.

**HTML**

```
 <select id="model" name="model" class="soflow-color">
                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select Car Model</option>
            </select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#make').change(function() {

        $year=$("#year option:selected").val();
        $make=$("#make option:selected").text().toLowerCase();

        $make=$make.replace(/\s/g,"-");
        $('#model').html("");
        var obj={
            year:$year,
            make:$make,
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>Home/ajax_search_step2',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:obj,

            beforeSend: function(){

                var target = document.getElementById('make-spinner')
                var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
                $(target).data('spinner', spinner);

            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#make-spinner').data('spinner').stop();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    $('#model').append("<option value='"+value.model_name+"'>"+value.model_name+"</option>");
                });
            }
        });

        $('#trim').html("<option selected='true' disabled='disabled'>Select Car Trim</option>");
    });
```

this was working fine for the case of simple select but what i want is to add search feature and i preferred the plugin above.

but when i tried to add some options into it it is not working! the html that is generated is totally different from what we have usually in select! any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did it myself!

the updated version which allows you dynamically refresh the select list instead of changing the contents what i needed is to add this

```
 $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
```

so basically it becomes!

```
 success: function (data) {
                    $('#model').replaceAll('');
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        $('#model').append("<option value='"+value.model_name+"'>"+value.model_name+"</option>");
                    });
 $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
                }
```